# Why Argument Dependent Lookup doesn't work with function template dynamic_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

Consider the following C++ program:

```
#include <memory>

struct A {};

struct B : A {};

int main()
{
    auto x = std::make_shared<A>();
    if (auto p = dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(x));
}
```

When compiling with MSVC 2010, I obtain the following error:

```
error C2065: 'dynamic_pointer_cast' : undeclared identifier
```

The error persists if `auto` is replaced by `std::shared_ptr<A>`. When I fully qualify the call with `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`, the program successfully compiles.

Also, [gcc 4.5.1](http://ideone.com/Z28dC) doesn't like it either:

```
error: 'dynamic_pointer_cast' was not declared in this scope
```

I thought that `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` would have been picked by [Koenig lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup), since the type of `x` lives in the `std` namespace. What am I missing here ?

Comment: What does making it **std::dynamic_pointer_cast** throws up ?

Comment: @DumbCoder: like I said, the program compiles when I use `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`. I'm just curious about why the compiler does not pick `dynamic_pointer_cast` by ADL.

Comment: Sorry skimmed that part, my bad !!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think section §14.8.1/6 (C++03, and I think it holds in C++11 also) applies to this case which reads as,

> [Note: For simple function names, argument dependent lookup (3.4.2) applies even when the function name is not visible within the scope of the call. This is because the call still has the syntactic form of a function call (3.4.1). **But when a function template with explicit template arguments is used, the call does not have the correct syntactic form unless there is a function template with that name visible at the point of the call. If no such name is visible, the call is not syntactically well-formed and argument-dependent lookup does not apply.** If some such name is visible, argument dependent lookup applies and additional function templates may be found in other namespaces.
>
> [Example:
>
> ```
> namespace A {
>      struct B { };
>      template<int X> void f(B);
> }
> namespace C {
>      template<class T> void f(T t);
> }
> void g(A::B b) {
>      f<3>(b);    //ill-formed: not a function call
>      A::f<3>(b); //well-formed
>      C::f<3>(b); //ill-formed; argument dependent lookup
>                  // applies only to unqualified names
>
>     using C::f;
>      f<3>(b); //well-formed because C::f is visible; then
>               // A::f is found by argument dependent lookup
> }
> ```
>
> —end example] —end note]

Your case do not trigger ADL because you explicitly pass template argument **and** there is no template with the same name available at the site where you call `dynamic_pointer_cast`.

One trick to enable ADL is to add a dummy template with *same* name to your code, as shown below:

```
#include <memory>

struct A {};

struct B : A {};

template<int> //template parameter could be anything!
void dynamic_pointer_cast(); //ADD this. NO NEED TO DEFINE IT

int main()
{
   auto x = std::make_shared<A>();
   if (auto p = dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(x)); //now it should work through ADL
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I think we can assume this still holds for C++11. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexandreC.: I think it holds in C++11 also.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: The trick is basically an obvious corollary of the text I quoted.

Comment: @AlexandreC: This appears unchanged in n3337 in §14.8.1/8 [temp.arg.explicit].

Answer (score 18):

Koenig lookup only applies to finding functions.  Here, you first have to find a template, then instantiate it, before you have a function.  In order to simply parse the code, the compiler has to know that `dynamic_pointer_cast` is a template (otherwise, '<' is less than, and not the start of a template argument list); until the compiler knows that `dynamic_pointer_cast` is a function template, it doesn't even know that a function call is involved.  The expression it sees is basically `a < b > c`, where `<` and `>` are the relational operators.

Comment: It seems that Koenig lookup can find function templates too, cf. Nawaz's answer. Nonetheless, your argument is the right one.

Comment: Pedantically speaking, Koenig lookup applies to function template as well. It just doesn't work when you explicitly pass template argument and the template name isn't visible at the site of the call. In this case, it doesn't work because the call doesn't have correct function-call syntax, as the compiler doesn't know that the name is actually a name of function template.

Comment: @Nawaz In the end, it doesn't work because the standard says it doesn't, and there are several reasons why the standard doesn't say make it work.  Both the one you give and what I explained (which comes from discussions in the committee, many, many years back) go back to the same basic problem: in order to correctly parse the expression, the compiler has to know that the symbol is a template, and in order to know that, it has to look it up.  And it can't use Koenig lookup looking it up, because it hasn't yet parsed enough to know there is a function call.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Ohh.. I agree with that, then.